# How can I Set Week which starts from Friday and Ends on Next Thursday in DaterangePicker

Tags: momentjs, daterangepicker

I am Using JQuery [DateRangePicker](https://www.daterangepicker.com/) by Dan Grossman, right now I Configured it to enable Current Week's Dates only by momentjs.

Here is my script

```
var startDate = moment().startOf('week').toDate();
var endDate = moment().endOf('week').toDate();

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#paymentDateTimePicker").daterangepicker({
       singleDatePicker: true,
       autoUpdateInput: false,
       minDate: startDate,
       maxDate: endDate,
       locale: {
          format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
          firstDay: 1
       }
     });
});
```

By default, this configuration starts from Sunday to Saturday.
Here is the output.

[image]

Now I want to Configure this dateRangePicker to starts on Friday instead of Sunday and ends on Thursday.

OR **We can say From 2nd Of OCT to 8th of OCT.**

I tried the add() and subtract() Methods of momentjs but can not find a proper solution to this.

Help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your help, Above solution will work on regular days but if Today's Saturday then
it will not work.

here is a possible solution.

```
var day = moment().day();
        var startDate;
        var endDate;
        if (day >= 5) {
            startDate = moment().day(5).toDate();
            endDate = moment().day(5).add(6, 'days').toDate()
        }
        else {
             startDate = moment().startOf('week').subtract(2, 'days').toDate();
             endDate = moment().endOf('week').subtract(2, 'days').toDate();
        }
```

or can also use [Datejs](https://github.com/datejs/Datejs) for easy chaining.

Answer (score 0):

You can Modify as the date range from the Week Like This

```
var startDate = moment().startOf('week').subtract(2,'days').toDate();
var endDate = moment().endOf('week').subtract(2, 'days').toDate();
```